# Sitecore "Indexing is paused"

Tags: lucene, sitecore

I seem to be having some issues with the IntervalAsynchronousStrategy for updating content items.

Sometimes, the indexes will not be automatically updated with this strategy, and a manual index rebuild is required.

These are the corresponding log file entries:

8404 09:20:24 INFO [Index=artscentre_web_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy executing. 
8404 09:20:24 INFO [Index=artscentre_web_index] History engine is empty. Incremental rebuild returns 
8032 09:20:21 WARN [Index=artscentre_web_index] IntervalAsynchronousUpdateStrategy triggered but muted. Indexing is paused.

And I see this for every time the index rebuilds, even though there is content being edited and published in that time.

I have previously swapped from the OnPublishEnd rebuild strategy to the interval strategy as I was finding that publishing content would not trigger an index rebuild either.

Our environment is a single instance setup only, so the single IIS website handles both CM and CD. Therefore I can eliminate anything to do with remote events, I think?

Has anyone else had this much trouble getting Sitecore to maintain index updates?

Cheers, 
Justin

Comment: I've had a situation where a database restore of master and web from production to local caused an invalid history table and led to the same symptoms with the OnPublishEnd strategy. Let me know if you have done something similar, I believe we fixed it by restoring the core as well but I'm not sure.

Comment: do you also have problems with other indexes that are using the same strategy (core for example) ? Also can you please post your index configuration and strategy (if any) configuration  ?

Comment: @Juzzbot, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @testpattern - We did. In the end we had a Sitecore technician come on site and go through our indexing configurations. The main point that we did was to switch the rebuild strategy back to default OnPublishEnd.